# python login form with pandas not Working

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a login using my CSV file and i'm using pandas to read my csv file but i keep getting this error

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'brugernavn'

I can't seem to figured out if my csv file is setup wrong or my code ain't done correctly

```
import pandas as pd

 class Login:
   def Userlogin(self):
      userData = pd.read_csv('Csv/Users.csv')
      df = pd.DataFrame(userData)

      print('Log ind\n')
      user = input('Brugernavn : ')
      pasw = input('Password : ')

      matching_creds = (len(df[(df.brugernavn == user) & (df.password == pasw)]) > 0)

      if matching_creds:
          print('succes')
      else:
      print('kontakt admin')

LoginHandler = Login()
LoginHandler.Userlogin()
```

This is my CSV FILE

```
brugernavn;password;fornavn;efternavn;rolle;stilling
Val;1234;Valon;abc;1;Udvikler
Casper;1234;Casper;abc;1;Udvikler
Peter;1234;Peter;Blink;3;Teknikker
Grete;1234;Grete;Hansen;2;Administration
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that the csv is semicolon separated. I also fixed the password checker.

```
import pandas as pd

class Login:
    def Userlogin(self):
        userData = pd.read_csv('Csv/Users.csv', sep=';')
        df = pd.DataFrame(userData)
        print('Log ind\n')
        user = input('Brugernavn : ')
        pasw = input('Password : ')
        
        # get index of username if it exists
        index = df[df['brugernavn'] == user].index.values
        # see if the password matches for that user
        matching_creds = True if len(index) > 0 and str(df.at[index[0], 'password']) == pasw else False
        
        if matching_creds:
            print('succes')
        else:
            print('kontakt admin')

LoginHandler = Login()
LoginHandler.Userlogin()
```

As a side note, you never want to store passwords in plain text. You should store the **hash** of the password and compare the hashes.